# In chrome table borders get clipped with border-collapse and height 100%

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code in Chrome:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>  <style> td {
    border: 1px solid; }
     table {
         border-collapse: collapse; 

     }
     </style>       




    </head>
    <body> <div style="
    height: 50px; overflow: hidden; " class="clearfix"> <table style="
    height: 100%; ">
      <tbody><tr><td style="
    border:  1px solid; ">Test 1</td>
      <td style="
    border: 1px solid; ">Test 2</td>
      <td style="
    border: 1px solid; ">Test 3</td>
      <td>Test 4</td>
      <td>Test 5</td>

        </tr></tbody></table></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and the table borders appear to be clipped. If I remove border-collapse, it appears not to be clipped. In Firefox, it works fine.

[image: Table Clipped]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

remove overflow: hidden from div.

Comment: I need it to be there. Why is the behavior like this?